# Reasons for upgrading from Team Foundation Server 2008 to Team Foundation Server 2010

Tags: tfs, upgrade

Currently our team is using TFS 2008 and I need to substantiate my opinion to push my whole team forward.

**What are the must-have features of TFS 2010?

Or: What are your main reasons to upgrade from TFS 2008 to TFS 2010?**

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

Off the top of my head, these are what are important to me from a 2010 standpoint:

- Hierarchical work items (parent/child)
- Performance and Stability improvements
- The concept of project collections to allow for logically separate instances of TFS to be hosted on a single data tier.
- Ease of installation.
- Better rollback support.
- Better branching and merging visualization.
- Improved process templates and reports.

Comment: Merging is many orders of magnitude improved.  As in 2008 merging was borderline unusable in comparison.

Comment: Not to forget about the testing capabilities with Test and Lab manager

Answer (score 1):

Found an article on MSDN that describes all new jewels in Visual Studio 2010 Application Lifecycle Management

[What's New for Application Lifecycle Management in Visual Studio 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb385832.aspx)